# clamd randomly stops

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I am using clamav in conjuction with c-icap to filter content with squid.  I am also using the safebrowsing functionality of clamav to block access to bad domains.  For some reason or another, clamav (clamd), suddenly stops running and I see that the c-icap service cannot connect to socket clamd socket.  However, I don't see anything in the log files indicating why clamav suddenly stopped.

I checked the following basics:
1. clamav logs (syslog output)
2. free space
3. dmesg

[Unit]
Description = clamd scanner (%i) daemon
After = syslog.target nss-lookup.target network.target

```
[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart = /usr/sbin/clamd -c /etc/clamd.d/%i.conf --nofork=yes
#Restart = on-failure
Restart = always
PrivateTmp = true
PIDFile=/var/run/clamav/%i.pid

[Install]
Also=clamd@.socket
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any ideas what may be causing clamav to suddenly stop?

Comment: You say you checked the logs. What did they say? (Why did you conclude that they seem fine?) What do you mean by "stops running"? (Does the process die or does it stop responding?)

Comment: Does systemd tell you with what signals or exit codes clamd exited?

Comment: Also, can you present the clamd.service file? It can be different on different distros.

Comment: 1. logs do not indicate anything with clamd, only c-icap said it could not contact or connect to clamd. 2. it appears it was restarted by systemd now so I don't see any exit codes. 3. here is the service file I wrote, maybe it is not correct, originally, it had Restart=on-failure.

Comment: Perhaps the journal is doing the logging because --nofork=yes is used. Did you check the journal for anything?

Comment: Yes, I checked the journal (journalctl) and didn't see anything there.

Comment: If I have freshclam running periodically, could that cause any problems?  I wouldn't think it could/should.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't appear to be freshclam that is the problem, but it just appears to quit randomly and now with the change I made, it at least comes back on its own.

Comment: It exited again, the exit code is 0/SUCCESS.  That does not make any sense unless it was told to be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Set `Type = forking` in your `clamd.service` file.

Based on personal experience and the description of `simple` vs `forking` found [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)